# How do I check dependencies when invoking a sub-make to build when there are changes?

Tags: makefile, multiple-makefiles

If I have a makefile that calls another makefile, how to I get the master makefile to correctly check if the dependencies of the subordinate makefile have changed?

For example, if I have the rule

```
server:
     @cd $(SERVERDIR) && $(MAKE)
```

That invokes make in the subdirectory in which I build an executable "server". However, if I change one of the files that make up server, the parent make doesn't see the changes and refuses to rebuild server - "make: `server' is up to date."

How can I get the master makefile to correctly detect when there's a change in one of the dependent files (something like $(SERVERDIR)/server.c, for example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you want to use a phony target

```
.PHONY: server
server:
     @cd $(SERVERDIR) && $(MAKE)
```

There's a detailed description of the Phony target [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-g_t_002ePHONY-216), but the short description is you're telling the makefile that there will never be a file that corresponds with this server target, and therefore it won't consider server up to date if there is a file named server in the directory.

Comment: This would normally be a good solution, but I don't want to *always* rebuild the target, I want it to behave like a normal non-recursive target and only build when something has changed.

Comment: That is the responsibility of your sub-makefile.

Comment: What Randy said.  Since your server target doesn't have dependencies, it doesn't know "something has changed." Otherwise, what's the point of having the submakefile?

Answer (score 1):

Your target name matches the name of one of the files or directories in your main `Makefile` directory.

Assuming you need to build everything in a subdirectory called `server`, this rule:

```
server:
    $(MAKE) -C server
```

will not work, as the target `server` is a directory, has no source files and doesn't need to be built then.

This one:

```
srv:
    $(MAKE) -C server
```

will work, as long as there is no file or directory called `srv`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't:

- [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/)
- [Implementing non-recursive make](http://www.xs4all.nl/~evbergen/nonrecursive-make.html)

But yes, if you have no choice, e.g. because you don't control the sub-makefile, a `.PHONY` target is what you are looking for.